# Motion to change the tag datastorage to data-storage

Tags: discussion, tags

[datastorage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datastorage) combines a two word phrase into one, and is not commonly seen used interchangeably like the "meta data" and "metadata".

eg.,

- [search-results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-results)
- [domain-registration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-registration)
- [structured-data](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structured-data)

While this seems minuet, the canonical tag is not consistent with our existing taxonomy.

Comment: If there are no objections to the tag modification, I'll update it in a few days - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting the tag [rename](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag). That does fit better with our other tag naming convention, and seems to be more consistent with what's commonly being used.

Since there weren't any objections, I renamed the `datastorage` tag to [data-storage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-storage). The changes are effective immediately and all previous questions were retagged accordingly.